# Avoid Title Case for Acronyms

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of lines of data in my dataframe that are all caps and have names such as SAP HANA or FOX CORPORATION or APPLE INC.

I am using the following formula to adjust these to the proper cases:

```
df['Stock'] = df['Stock'].str.title()
```

The only issue is that this screws up acronyms that are supposed to be all caps (e.g. SAP vs Sap). Is there a way to create a list of these acronyms and exclude them from the function? Or is there a way to use regex to go back and replace those terms in the column? The only issue that I am running into is sometimes it's just SAP, sometimes its SAP ____, and how do I NOT adjust where the sequence S A P shows up in the middle of a different sentence (e.g. dont change Sapori Trattoria to SAPori Trattoria).

Comment: Other than "I just know", how can you tell if it's an acronym or not?

Comment: That's about it... think about all of the company names there are out there... there's no real rule to follow. That's why I think holding a list of terms to look for would make the most sense (e.g. look for SAP, look for GE, look for HP, etc.)

Comment: Are words always separated by a space or do thet contain commas and other symbols?

Answer (score 0):

This list of acronyms could be pretty huge, so I don't recommend ignoring it in regex. Instead, you could use split each company name on spaces, and use `title()` on each word if it's not an acronym, before joining it. Also, make it a *set* of acronyms instead of a list, because membership checking in a set is O(1) as opposed to O(n) for a list.

```
acronyms = {'SAP', 'HP', 'GE'}

def title_case_not_acronyms(orig_str):
    words = orig_str.split(" ")
    words_tc = [word if word in acronyms else word.title() for word in words]
    return " ".join(words)
```

Now, apply this to your column using `df["Stock"].apply(title_case_not_acronyms)`.